# how can one create a link between two issues using python jira api

Tags: python, api, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to automate some issue creation tasks that I need to perform.. Well, I don't like to click too much.

I have managed to create issues by

```
import jira

jira_conn = jira.JIRA('url_to_server')
issue_dict_a = dict(
    project={'key': 'ABC'},
    summary='summed up',
    description='',
    issuetype={'name': 'TypeA'},
)
iss_a = jira_conn.create_issue(fields=issue_dict_a)
# suppose this is issue ABC-1
# issue_dict_a = dict(...)
iss_b = jira_conn.create_issue(fields=issue_dict_b)
# suppose this is issue ABC-2
```

However, I then want to [link](https://jira.readthedocs.io/api.html#jira.client.JIRA.create_issue_link) them using something like

```
jira_conn.create_issue_link(typestr, inwardIssue='ABC-1', outwardIssue='CSV-2')
```

But what dows the `typestr` need to be? Where do I get the right type from? How is it specified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says the type of link between two issues.

In Jira, the issue can be below examples, so you can try them:

- "relates to"
- "duplicates" / "is duplicated by"
- "blocks" / "is blocked by"
- "clones" / "is cloned by"

Answer (score 2):

ah I just realized that it works, using the string from the link to menu.

For example `typestr = "blocks"`.

I hope that helps somebody.. :-)

Comment: oh I just noticed you've found the answer!